# newcommand containing tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I am using tikz-qtree to draw a binary tree.
As I need to have them labeled I wanted to ues the following macro which work in ordinary tikz:

```
\newcommand{\A}[1]{\node(a#1){Activity #1};}
```

However, this does not work; the error is that node is an undefined control sequence.

Of course this macro is used inside a `tikzpicture`, so basically I just want to dump `\node(a1){Activity 1};` if `\A{1}` is called. I am pretty sure it has to do with my TeXnic. . . Maybe expansion?

Note, the tikz-qtree manual states that

> `\Tree` specifically watches out for the token `\node`; do not use `\path node` or other equivalents.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-qtree}
\newcommand{\A}[1]{\node(a#1){Activity #1};}
\begin{document}
Works:\
\tikz\A{1};
\hfill
Works:
\Tree [.\node(a1){A1}; 1 2 ]
\hfill
Doesn't Work:
% \begin{tikzpicture}
%   \Tree [.\A{1} b c ]
% \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you suspected, the problem is related to expansion: `\Tree` is expanded first and looks for its parameters before expanding `\A`. The problem can be solved if `\A` is expanded first. The `\expandafter` primitive allows you to do this: the sequence

```
\expandafter<token1><token2>
```

is replaced by

```
<token1><expansion of token2>
```

and this replacement is reexamined by the expansion processor.

Since you also have to take into account the tokens `[` and `.` you'll need three `\expandafter` commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-qtree}

\newcommand{\A}[1]{\node(a#1){Activity #1};}

\begin{document}

\expandafter\Tree \expandafter[\expandafter.\A{A} 1 2 ]

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \expandafter\Tree \expandafter[\expandafter.\A{1} b c ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: My tree consists of `\A`'s only actually. It seems that  `\expandafter\Tree \expandafter[\expandafter.\A{1} \expandafter\A{2} c ]` doesn't work.

Comment: @Rasmus: I doubt that finding and maintaining the correct `\expandafter` sequence is easier that writing the `\node` directly.

Comment: @Rasmus: I agree with Ulrike Fischer. Doing some tests, as the tree grows, the host of `\expandafter`s will render the code almost impossible to read; it's even difficult to find the exact sequence that they should follow.

Comment: @Ulrike, @Gonzalo, yeah I agree. Given the current solution it is not practical. Had it been possible to write `\Tree [.\A{1} \A{2} \A{3} ]` it would have been much more clean. Oh well. Thanks, though.

Comment: I would really like to see a solution with \Tree [.\A{1} \A{2} \A{3} ] as the syntax for the actual tree. This would be extremely useful for linguistics.