# Use of \Tree with a macro

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, tikz-qtree

I am using the `qtree` to produce some trees, for example with this syntax `\Tree [.foo bar ]`.

Now, I have automated some part of the tree and get troubles. When I place `[.foo bar ]` inside of a macro, qtree doesn't accept to generate the tree: `Use of \@subtree doesn't match its definition`.

I am sure the solution is quite simple but I can't find it.

Here is a sample code.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,qtree,tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\inputtree}{[.foo bar ]}

%%%\Tree \inputtree %%This line doesn't compile
\Tree [.foo bar ]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\expandafter\Tree \inputtree` might work.

Comment: Shouldn't `\newcommand` come before `\begin{document}`? (I'm on a computer without LaTeX so I can't test it.)

Comment: I don't recommend using both `tikz-qtree` *and* `qtree` since they both define the `\Tree` macro.  Most likely the `tikz-qtree` definition overrides the `qtree` one, but it's still not advisable.

Comment: Since the code may be useful to others, I have posted a dedicated question here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155316/generate-a-tree-diagram-from-a-file-with-qtree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is similar to [newcommand containing tikz node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20314/newcommand-containing-tikz-node), which however could be misleading.

You need to make `\Tree` “see” the bracket, so the macro must be expanded before TeX tries do work with `\Tree`:

```
\expandafter\Tree \inputtree
```

will do.